# Simple setTimeout not working?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to create a basic script in Tampermonkey. I would like to visit one URL, wait 1 second and then visit another:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    setTimeout(doStuff ,1000);
});

function doStuff(){
    document.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
```

The function `doStuff` does not appear to be called ever. Whenever I run the script, I get redirected to google.com, but then not to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A JavaScript execution environment only lasts for the lifetime of the page.

When you set `location.href` you leave the page, so any pending JavaScript won't run because its environment no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use iframes to accomplish your goal  This will do what you are looking for:

```
<body>
  <iframe style='width: 100%; height: 100%;' id='myframe' />
</body>
```

Then change your `document.location.href` to `document.getElementById('myframe').src = 'URL HERE';`

This way the user will never technically leave your screen, and you can change which page they are viewing.

Comment: Security sandbox could interfere tho